# How to get the list of non-system databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying:

`SHOW DATABASES WHERE 'Database' NOT IN ('mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys');`

But the `mysql`, `performance_schema` and `sys` appear in the list.

Comment: You are using single quotes on the database name where no quoting is needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` NOT IN ('mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys')
```

Just replace `'Database'` with `` `Database` ``

Answer (score 0):

```
show databases where `Database` not regexp 'schema|sys|mysql';
```

seems to work as well